# How remove all the longest the strings in a vector of strings

Tags: java

// this program  prints all the shortest elements in a vector of String

I want this program to print all the shortest strings in the vector. The output should be `hello,test,JAVA`. The last word is not being removed. Can anybody help, because the condition is clear, I think. If it's the same length, it should be removed.

```
import java.util.Vector;

class printAllSmallInVectorOfString
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vector<String> v=new Vector();

        v.addElement("hello");
        v.addElement("test");
        v.addElement("phytons");
        v.addElement("JAVA");
        v.addElement("Program");
        v.addElement("ultrons");


        String largest="";  // define largest

        for(int i=0 ; i < v.size() ; i++)
        {
            // checks if first element is longer
            if( largest.length() <  v.elementAt(i).length())
            {
                // largest stores the string
                largest=v.elementAt(i);
            }
            // condition for elements of same length
            else if(v.elementAt(i).length() == largest.length())   
            {
                System.out.println("The largest element so far is " + largest + " at index " + v.indexOf(largest ));
                System.out.println(v.elementAt(i) + " at index " + v.indexOf(v.elementAt(i)) + " is the same length as the largest element " + largest + "\n");
                // removes second element which is equal with longest
                 v.removeElementAt(i);
            }


        }
        // removes longest element
        v.removeElementAt(v.indexOf(largest));

         for(String z : v)
         System.out.println(z);


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a `Vector`, it's deprecated.

Comment: yes i know but im only doing this because im about to do exam in a couple of weeks and theres a question in the study guide which ask us to do that to actually return a vector of all the shortest strings

Comment: Your logic is flawed. If you want to print the shortest strings in the vector, first use a loop that determines the shortest string and then use another loop which removes all elements that are longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution without any Java 8 features.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector<String> v = new Vector();

    v.addElement("hello");
    v.addElement("test");
    v.addElement("phytons");
    v.addElement("JAVA");
    v.addElement("Program");
    v.addElement("ultrons");

    System.out.println(keepShortest(v));
}

public static List<String> keepShortest(List<String> strings) {
    // Find length of shortest string
    int shortest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (string.length() < shortest) {
            shortest = string.length();
        }
    }

    // Populate new list with shortest strings
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (string.length() == shortest) {
            newList.add(string);
        }
    }

    return newList;
}
```

As I've said above, you need to:

- Find the length of the shortest string first
- Then remove all strings which are longer; or populate a new list with all strings of equal length

Comment: This is confusing because it takes a `List` and returns a `List` but it also mutates the input. If you return a `List`, then return a `new List`, if you mutate the input, `return void`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You are right; that might be a little confusing. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it thusly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Collection<String> strings = Arrays.asList(
            "hello",
            "test",
            "phytons",
            "JAVA",
            "Program",
            "ultrons"
    );

    final int min = strings.stream()
            .mapToInt(String::length)
            .min()
            .getAsInt();

    final Collection<String> shortest = strings.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.length() == min)
            .collect(toList());

    shortest.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

First, don't use `Vector`.

Now, get the minimum length of of the `String` in the `Collection`.

Then take the `Collection` and `filter` for `String` of that length.

Finally, loop over and print then contents of the `Collection`.

Comment: im not yet good on collections but isnt there a wayto combine collections with vector

Comment: @ColinAnacoura a [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) _is a_ `Collection`.